# null pointer exception coming while running integration test in eclipse

Tags: java

I am getting same null pointer exception while running integration test  in eclipse .while the test are passing when i run the same in command prompt .previously  the test was also passing in eclipse  but now i getting the problem

error is ::

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:103)
    at java.io.FileInputStream.<init>(FileInputStream.java:66)
    at java.io.FileReader.<init>(FileReader.java:41)
    at com.cmates.AbstractDBUnitSupport.getReader(AbstractDBUnitSupport.java:465)
    at com.cmates.AbstractDBUnitSupport.executeSqlFile(AbstractDBUnitSupport.java:329)
    at com.cmates.authorization.RegistrantProvisionsServiceImplIntTest.dropTables(RegistrantProvisionsServiceImplIntTest.java:96)
    at com.cmates.authorization.RegistrantProvisionsServiceImplIntTest.tearDown(RegistrantProvisionsServiceImplIntTest.java:105)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:44)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:15)
    at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:41)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.RunAfters.evaluate(RunAfters.java:37)
    at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:236)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit4.runner.JUnit4TestReference.run(JUnit4TestReference.java:45)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.TestExecution.run(TestExecution.java:38)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:460)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.runTests(RemoteTestRunner.java:673)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.run(RemoteTestRunner.java:386)
    at org.eclipse.jdt.internal.junit.runner.RemoteTestRunner.main(RemoteTestRunner.java:196)
```

Comment: Next time ask yourself this question: "How can others tell me what's wrong with my code when I'm not showing them the code"

Comment: i think the problem is not with code .the test case are passing when i run them thought command prompt .I think i am having some problem in setting of eclipse.the test case are failing only when i run directly from eclipse ..

Comment: I've rarely seen a programming problem not to be related to code ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The constructor of `FileInputStream` throws a `NullPointerException` if the `File` parameter is `null`. That's where you have to start searching. Maybe you want to read a sql file that can't be resolved from the "test environment".

Comment: thanxs ..the problem was ip address got changed and i didnot change it in my local.prop file .now it working ..

Answer (score 0):

The method `RegistrantProvisionsServiceImplIntTest.dropTables()` is trying to execute an SQL file but cannot find it. You may have to refresh the project in eclipse. It could also be an issue of access rights.

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to use an incorrectly initialized database connection.

Are you sure you use the "Setup + teardown" facility in JUnit correctly?